# C# Открытие архива через внешнее приложение

Tags: c#, rar

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно открывать архивы через внешнее приложение(explorer или всякие архиваторы)? Пробовал через Process.Start , но почему то после срабатывания метода архив ломается и не открывается(При открытии выдает ошибку - the archive is either in unknown format or damaged).

```
var filePath = Settings.TempDirectory + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(realname) ? fileName : realname);
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileContent);
                var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = filePath,
                    ErrorDialog = true,

                };
                Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Что значит "архив ломается"?

Comment: потому что так вы не открываете архив, а пытаетесь его запустить, как если бы это был исполняемый файл. Вам ниже уже написали как использовать 7zip для открытия. Не устраивает 7zip - ищите в реестре сопоставленную с расширением файла программу и указывайте ее для открытия. То что вы можете в интерфейсе ОС это сделать двойным кликом означает только то, что ОС сама составляет необходимую команду на основе данных реестра и исполняет ее.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Архив больше не открывается, выдает ошибку - the archive is either in unknown format or damaged

Comment: @MrStacky По поводу открытия файла ассоциированной программой, советую почитать тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows ... Если вкратце, то `Process.Start("archive.zip")` не прокатит.

Comment: @ГеннадийП понял, спасибо) почитаю

Comment: Почему это обычный процесс старт не прокатит? Вроде по ссылке речь не об этом и всё работало локально на форматах zip и png.

Comment: `WriteAllBytes` - это зачем? Наверняка вы сами ломаете архив, неправильным копированием.

Answer (score 2):

Как один из возможных вариантов. Если у вас в системе установлен [7z](https://www.7-zip.org), то с помощью его менеджера 7zFM можно открыть архив следующим образом:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe";
    processStartInfo.Arguments = @"D:\nuget.7z";
    Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

В результате у вас запуститься окно менеджера архивов 7z(которым мы привыкли пользоваться, когда используем 7z), где вы увидите распакованный архив *nuget.7z*

Для того, чтобы открыть **архив с ассоциированной программой**, сделайте так

```
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.FileName = @"D:\nuget.7z";
    Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: будьте любезны пояснить за что минус? Что ваc смущает?

Comment: минус не мой, но за 7-Zip тоже могу добавить

Comment: Я вроде написал ПОЯСНИТЕ. Чем вам 7ź не внешний архиватор с окном "эксплоера" для просмотра содержимого?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Я так понял, что человеку нужно открывать архивы ассоциированной с ними программой. Откуда вы знаете, что у человека стоит 7Zip? А может WinRAR или еще какая экзотическая программа, или вообще стандартным проводником открывает?

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/907a9e5e8f67c66745088804e5ff6b66939ab3113567d96074a4778b0f95dd41/relations

Comment: @Геннадий П  Я так понял, что человеку нужно открывать архивы ассоциированной с ними программой.(с) 
Именно так

Comment: @MrStacky, внес изменения в ответ.

Comment: UseShellExecute разве не истина по умолчанию?

Comment: по умолчанию истина.